# control is not coming to view i. JSP /HTML in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am new in Spring boot. I have created a Spring boot project(Spring MVC + JDBC) from Spring initializer https://start.spring.io/. My MVC controller is working fine i.e the control is coming to the controller. From the controller, the control is not going to view (JSP/HTML). I have mentioned the JSP path also in application.properties as follows. The control is not going to JSP. I also tried with HTML but the control is not going to any HTML also. Please let me know if anyone can help me out with this.

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

I have also included below dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your Controller class ?

Comment: I got the issue. The JSP was inside the WEB-INF/views folder. Now renamed the WEB-INF folder. But now there is a new issue that the JSP/HTML is just getting downloaded in the form of a file. I want the JSP to be rendered as  JSP/HTML. Can you please suggest any solution for this..